# Yii session: cant set lifetime ~ 30 days

Tags: php, yii

Trying to increase lifetime from default ~ 8 hours to 30 days.
Work here: [CWebUser](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser/)

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();

    $lifetime = 15;       // work!  (even without setting gc_maxlifetime)
    $lifetime = 2592000;  // DONT work!  (auto logout in ~8 hours )

    $this->authTimeout = $lifetime;
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $lifetime); 

    Yii::app()->getSession()->open();

    (other code...)
}
```

If i set value low - it works, 30 days - dont.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @SiZE Its auto logout in ~8 hours still..

Comment: According to a PHP docs: If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive `session.gc_maxlifetime` together with `session.save_path`.

Comment: Also, max value for `session.gc_maxlifetime` is 65535. Values bigger than this may cause php session stops working.

Comment: By the way sessions shoudn't live so long. If you want store data for a long  time use another storages like db, files, etc,.